# IEnumerable<entity> return incorrect data from my table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an entity named Affaire as below:

```
    [Key]
    public string IdAffaire { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
```

I also have an entity named Suite as below:

```
    [Key]
    public string IdSuite { get; set; }
    public string IdAffaire { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdAffaire")]
    public virtual Affaire Affaire { get; set; }
```

One affaire can have multiple suites. 
Each suite is related to one affaire.

In my suite table, I have the following records:

```
IdSuite/IdAffaire/Description
0001/12.345/Description1
0001/13.666/DescriptionA
0002/13.666/DescriptionB
0003/13.666/DescriptionC
0004/13.666/DescriptionD
```

The problem: in my code, if I try to get a list of all suites, I get the following:

```
IEnumerable<Suite> suites

0001/12.345/Description1
0001/12.345/DescriptionA
0002/13.666/DescriptionB
0003/13.666/DescriptionC
0004/13.666/DescriptionD
```

As you can see, something's wrong with the data returned??

Do you have an idea?

Thank you very much :)

Edited for posting code:

```
... 
IEnumerable<Suite> suites;
...
```

When I debug this line of code and inspect the suites variable, I received wrong result (as showed up).

**Maybe the problem is that I need to define correctly my primary key on table Suite: composed of two fields IdAffaire an IdSuite** How can I do?

Comment: How are you getting the data? Please post the code.

Comment: What Oded said. Also, your `IdSuite` seems to be non-unique, and `DescriptionA` has `IdAffaire` different in the two result sets. Copy paste error?

Comment: @Dysaster: that's right: IdSuite is non-unique because my primary key on table Suite is composed of the two fields: IdAffaire + IdSuite. I don't know how to define it in my class? That's not a copy/paste error. That's really what I get. I updated my question for posting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem: because I have a composite primary key, I need to define it like this:

Suite entity:

```
[Key, Column(Order=0)]
public string IdSuite { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order=1)]
public string IdAffaire { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("IdAffaire")]
public virtual Affaire Affaire { get; set; }
```

Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

**Affaire class**

```
    [Key]
    public string IdAffaire { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Suite> Suites {get;set;}
```

**Suite Class**

```
[Key]
public string IdSuite { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }

[Required]
public string AffaireId { get; set; }
public virtual Affaire Affaire { get; set; }
```

---

**Creating objects**

```
Affaire aff= new Affaire{
             Title="An Affair",
              Note="Iam note of affair"
}



Suite suite1= new Suite{
               Description="Iam Description of suite 1",
               Affaire=aff  
            };
Suite suite2= new Suite{
               Description="Iam Description of suite 2",
               Affaire=aff  
            };
Suite suite3= new Suite{
               Description="Iam Description of suite 3",
               Affaire=aff  
            };

DbContext.Affaires.Add(aff);
DbContext.Suites.Add(suite1);
DbContext.Suites.Add(suite2);
DbContext.Suites.Add(suite3);
```